# WPF: DataTemplate with Collection and LocalTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

Do somebody know how to Link a collection of an ObservableCollection object to an OwnUserControl, which is integrated inside a DataTemplate in a WPF application? I have tried several Binding Path(Binding Path=MAIN-QUESTION in WPF Code) but i doesnt work. So i think maybe i have a basic misunderstanding from the concept here.

The ViewModel:

```
public class MyViewModel
{

private ObservableCollection<object> _timeLineCollection = new ObservableCollection<object>();
public ObservableCollection<object> TimeLineCollection
        {
            get { return _timeLineCollection; }
            set { _timeLineCollection = value; }
        }
}
```

WPF

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsControlOverview"  ItemsSource="{Binding TimeLineCollection}">
<ItemsControl.Resources>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:TimeLineTicketViewModel}">
                                <localtemplates:TimeLineTicket DataContext="{Binding Path=MAIN-QUESTION}" x:Name="TimeLineTicket"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Thanks for your help!

Regards
sittingduck

Comment: Where is MAIN-QUESTION located? In what class

Comment: MAIN-QUESTION is an object inside the TimeLineCollection. TimeLineCollection contains several objects type. The goal is to show them with ItemControl and Datatemplate. For easy maintenance i want to move the existing code of datatemplate to a usercontrol.

Comment: With the XAML you provided you're looking for an object MAIN-QUESTION inside each TimeLineTicketViewModel inside TimeLineCollection. I'm not sure about what you're trying to achieve but it's apparently not that

Comment: no actually not. At the time being i put bunch of xaml code in between <DataTemplate>. I simply want to replace this with an usercontrol, which contains the old code.

Comment: Maybe provide this bunch of xaml so we can work with something that actually work and show what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the ItemTemplate property of the ItemsControl instead of Resource.
[ItemTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<ItemsControl Name="ItemsControlOverview"  ItemsSource="{Binding TimeLineCollection}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:TimeLineTicketViewModel}">
                            <localtemplates:TimeLineTicket DataContext="{Binding Path=MAIN-QUESTION}" x:Name="TimeLineTicket"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Unfortunately itemscontrol.itemtemplate cannot hold more than one datatemplate type. Since i have several datatype on the collection, this sollution isnt practicable. Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, i have forget to initialize the usercontrol. Very amateurish failure.

Deeply sorry for the confussioness

Regards